# In AWS EC2 is there a way to view changes to the security rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a scaling server system in EC2 which only the client has had issues with it's deployment. The servers will randomly not be able to access outbound traffic especially on port 80 and 443.

I believe the client has maliciously done this to generate more work for me in developing system recovery code which they didn't want to pay for.

I have admin access to their AWS account and I want to know if there's an log I can access that shows changes in the security groups rules? Specifically the outbound traffic.

Comment: There are many other ways to prevent an EC2 instance from making outbound network requests that you won't find simply by investigating Security Group rule changes. For example subnet NACLs, stripping public IPs, removing IGW, local firewalls on the instances, routing traffic through a device that drops specific outbound packets. Also be aware of VPC Reachability Analyzer.

Answer (score 4):

The first option would be to inspect [CloudTrail Event history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/view-cloudtrail-events.html). The history stores only 90 days of events, unless you have enabled full [trial](https:///) for the account.

CloudTrail is only for retrospective analyses. If you want ongoing monitoring of changes to your infrastructure, you could set up [AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html) which provides a detailed view of changes as well as allows for automated response to unwanted changes.